# Why does Visual Studio Code with Python extension not import "fractions" library correctly?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When using Visual Studio Code with the Python extension, I am getting errors when trying to import 'fractions' Python library. This error does not occur with IDLE, CMD/Terminal, or other IDEs like Spyder.

Python script:

```
from fractions import Fraction as frac
print(frac(10,100))
```

Error:

```
  File "c:\PyCode\LearningScripts\fractions.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fractions import Fraction as frac
**ImportError: cannot import name 'Fraction'**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my environment, it works properly.

Therefore, I would recommend you to change the name of your file to something else since **'fractions.py' is a built-in module**, and delete the folder **__pycache__** just in case.

Then, try to run it again.